# Passing credentials inside docker container with the help of wrapper script as an env variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

In my dockerfile:::-

```
   ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /apps/service.jar --spring.profiles.active=$env --spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=$configRepo \
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=$password --spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=$username \
```

I have removed the `$username` and `$password` in ENV instruction in my dockerfile but still the same credentials are required to pass inside the ENTRYPOINT instruction but I dont have these credentials anymore in my dockerfile file.

Question: Is there a safer way to use those credentials in ENTRYPOINT at run-time?
Do I need to create a wrapper script and call that wrapper at run-time? How can I add these git logins to a wrapper script so that the script can be called at run-time?

I need to use credentials as env at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can directly [read properties from environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).  That means you don't need to include them in this command line at all

```sh
# Don't set individual Spring options as command-line options here
CMD java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /apps/service.jar
```

but instead you can pass them in when you start the container.  In Compose syntax:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: production
      SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_URI: git@git.example.com:repo
      SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_USERNAME: deploy
      SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD: redacted
```

**Do not include usernames or passwords in your Dockerfile.**  `docker history` can show the plain text of any command that was run to build the image; `docker inspect` will show the final values of any `ENV` statements; and you can `docker run` a container to show specific values.

Comment: Putting secrets in environment vars is very risky and considered bad practice in general. The preferred method is to mount a volume in memory that has the creds in a file, which you can then read and use without creating env vars. Env vars can be read by anyone with access to the docker daemon.

Comment: Actually I am using kubernetes. So, can I do changes in existing deployment configurations in order to pass these git login credentials at run-time instead of passing them as ENTRYPOINT in dockerfile?

Comment: Store them in a Secret (which again can be read back by anyone with access to the cluster, unless RBAC prohibits it).

Comment: Can I pass these git credentials as env variable at run-time within the kubernetes in the form of wrapper script instead of ENTRYPOINT in dockerfile?